Closed form : $\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{1}{x^4-2x^2+2} dx $
How to find the  Closed form :
$$\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{1}{x^4-2x^2+2} dx $$
\begin{align*}
I&=\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{1}{x^4-2x^2+2} dx=\frac{1}{2i}\int^{\infty}_{1} \frac{1}{x^2-1-i} - \frac{1}{x^2-1+i}dx\\&= \frac{1}{2i}\left[{\frac{e^{-3i\pi/8}}{2^{1/4}}\arctan\left({\frac{x}{2^{1/4}e^{3i\pi/8}}}\right)-\frac{e^{3i\pi/8}}{2^{1/4}}\arctan\left({\frac{x}{2^{1/4}e^{-3i\pi/8}}}\right)}\right]^{\infty}_{1}\\&=-\frac{\pi}{2^{3/4}}\sin\left({\frac{3\pi}{8}}\right)+\frac{i}{2^{3/4}}\left({e^{-3i\pi/8}\arctan\left({\frac{e^{-3i\pi/8}}{2^{1/4}}}\right)-e^{3i\pi/8}\arctan\left({\frac{e^{3i\pi/8}}{2^{1/4}}}\right)}\right)
\end{align*}
How can I simplify the result further? Are there other ways to find the closed form of this integral? I appreciate your interest.٩

@Claude Leibovici

Hint: $x^4-2x^2+2 = (x^2+\sqrt{2+2\sqrt 2}x+\sqrt 2) (x^2-\sqrt{2+2\sqrt 2}x+\sqrt 2)$ will help you avoid complex numbers.

@jjagmath Good hint. Please write the answer.

This is not a homework service. Write the answer yourself.

You could use https://www.integral-calculator.com/ it also gives you the steps

@ClaudeLeibovici For this integration. Any help?

Why not to stay with complex numbers after the partial fraction decomposition ? The result is nice.

@jjagmath yes but not for a long Time. Cheers

Exact result added

With $a_\pm=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt2\pm 1}2}$, the result simplifies to
$$I= \frac1{4\sqrt2}\bigg(\frac{\pi-\cot^{-1}a_-}{a_-}-\frac{\coth^{-1}a_+}{a_+} \bigg)$$.

Too long for a comment.
As you wrote $$I=\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{1}{x^4-2x^2+2}\, dx=\frac i 2 \int^{\infty}_{1}\Bigg(\frac{1}{x^2-(1-i)}-\frac{1}{x^2-(1+i)}   \Bigg) \,dx$$ Then
$$I=\frac{i}{2}  \left(\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-i}\right)}{\sqrt{1-i}}-\frac{\tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+i}\right)}{\sqrt{1+i}}\right)$$
or
$$I=\frac 14 \left( (1+i)^{3/2} \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+i}\right)-(1-i)^{3/2} \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-i}\right) \right)$$
seem to be the simplest forms of $I$.
Everything becomes very complicated if you try to expand $\sqrt{1\pm i}$ in terms of $\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)$ and $\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)$.
Inverse symbolic calculators do not find anything looking like $0.5301166461353718584494007$
Edit
Many thanks to @Mariusz Iwaniuk who gave the exact result
$$I=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}} \left(\pi -\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}\right)\right)+$$
$$\frac{1}{8 \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}\log \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2
   \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}}\right)$$

Nice result    .thank's
